# My Son's passport expires within 5 month our flight is next week

Tags: passports, canada, paperwork, israeli-citizens

My son's passport expires within 5 month, he holds an israeli passport and we fly directly to Toronto from Israel. Is it a problem and I just must renew it? I'm asking because of the eTA issue, it has to be the same passport number. If Ill renew it I will receive a new passport number... I have a huge dilemma because of it. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: If you decide to renew the passport, yes, you must get a new ETA.  It's only seven dollars, though (<20 ILS), so it shouldn't be a huge dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

Canada does not appear to have "6 month rule". From [the government website](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html):

> All international travellers must carry acceptable identification and a valid visa (if necessary) when entering Canada. A passport is recommended because it is the only reliable and universally-accepted travel and identification document for the purpose of international travel.

I did a search on that whole site for "6 months" and did not find any indication of how long a passport needs to be valid for. I also checked a handful of "travel tips" articles that mentioned the rule and did not include Canada in the list of countries with the rule, though most such articles (perhaps all) were aimed at US passport holders, and the rule if it did exist would almost certainly not apply to US passport holders.

You can check with the Canadian ETA people directly using this form: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta-form-help.asp and ask them if 5 months on the passport is an issue, and if it is what that means for the ETA, but it seems to me that it won't be an issue. (I recommend you ask them anyway to put your mind fully at ease.)

Comment: I couldn't find anything from the Canadian government either, but the [UK government travel advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/canada/entry-requirements) explicitly states no validity beyond the length of stay is required.

Comment: I checked on this extensively last summer and could not get explicit confirmation of the lack of a six month rule.  All they would do is repeat the information on the web. We had no trouble entering Canada with a passport that was about one month from expiration.

Answer (score 2):

TIMATIC, the database used by airlines, is crystal clear:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid **for the period of intended stay.**

So no, you don't need to renew any passports.